# The bot doesn't warn me after saying a badwords

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a badword filters using sqlite3 on discord.py, it somehow doesn't send anything to me although I'm swearing with the word that listed on my db

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            db = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT text FROM badwords WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if result is None:
                return
            if result is not None:
                bword = [x[0] for x in result]
                if any(b in bword for b in message.content.lower()):
                    await message.channel.send("plz no swear my bot is noob")
                cursor.close()
                db.close()
```

[image: This is the database]

[image: This is the pict when I swear]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if any(b in bword for b in message.content.lower())` will iterate over every *character* in the input string instead of every word, so it will never match with any of your bad words. Instead, iterate over the separate words by splitting it with `message.content.lower().split(" ")`.